# where do I specify the node version in LifeRay studio project?

Tags: node.js, angular, gradle, gulp

I have a portlet project that is using an angular app as client side. The build script is a gradle script that executes a npmInstall task through the ExecuteGulpTask plugin. The problem is that npmInstall task get's running forever. I have done 'npm install' separately in DOS console without errors with Node 10.16.0. What I have found, is that the node version that the plugin is executing, is Node version 5.5.0 (in a generated 'build' folder). Don't know where this version come from and I guess is what is causing the problem. Where do I configure the Node version to be used by the Gulp Gradle plugin? or is it a configuration of Node in the portlet project? (I can't even find it in the Liferay developer studio 3.5 IDE). My PATH variable has node 10.16.0, npm 6.13.4, angular 7.1.3

These are the scripts

build.gradle

```
        buildscript {
            dependencies {
                classpath group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.gradle.plugins", version: "2.0.10"       
            }

            repositories {
                mavenLocal()

                maven {
                    url "https://cdn.lfrs.sl/repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public"
                }
            }
        }

        apply plugin: "com.liferay.plugin"
        apply plugin: "com.liferay.gulp"

        import com.liferay.gradle.plugins.gulp.ExecuteGulpTask

        task compileTypeScript(type: ExecuteGulpTask)

        compileTypeScript {
            dependsOn npmInstall

            gulpCommand = 'default'
        }

        classes {
            dependsOn compileTypeScript
        }

        dependencies {
            compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "2.0.0"
            compileOnly group: "javax.portlet", name: "portlet-api", version: "2.0"
            compileOnly group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.compendium", version: "5.0.0"
        }
```

package.json

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/common": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/core": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/forms": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/http": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/platform-server": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/router": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/upgrade": "~2.2.1",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
        "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.21",
        "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.2",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
        "promise-polyfill": "6.0.2",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
        "rxjs": "^5.4.3",
        "zone.js": "~0.7.7"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^6.0.48",
        "angular2-router-loader": "^0.3.4",
        "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.2.3",
        "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
        "gulp": "~3.9.1",
        "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
        "source-map-support": "^0.4.16",
        "to-string-loader": "^1.1.4",
        "typescript": "^2.4.2",
        "webpack": "2.2.1",
        "webpack-merge": "^3.0.0"
      },
```

Gulpfile.js

```
    var gulp = require("gulp");
    var gutil = require("gulp-util");
    var webpack = require("webpack");

    gulp.task("default", function(callback) {
        // run webpack
        webpack(require('./webpack.config.js'), function(err, stats) {      
            if (err)
                throw new gutil.PluginError("webpack:build", err);
            gutil.log("[webpack:build]", stats.toString({
                colors : true
            }));
            callback();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this configuration to your build.gradle file:

```
node {
    version = '10.15.1'
    npmVersion = '6.4.1'

    // If true, it will download node using above parameters.
    // If false, it will try to use globally installed node.
    download = false
}
```